# select2 banco de dados

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html5, jquery-select2

tenho um select2 que é populado do banco de dados
da tudo funcionando, recebe os dados do banco e etc.
porem se eu quiser editar ele nao traz a opção salva na tela somente no front se debugar ele esta la, ja no select normal ela traz de cara entendem

esse é o javascript

```
     $('.js-single').select2({
        allowClear: true,
        selectOnClose: true,
    })
```

esse e o html

```
<div class="es2 col-md-6">
              <label class="lb">País<label class="lb1" data-
            toggle="tooltip"
                title="ÁREA DE TEXTO OBRIGATÓRIO"> *</label></label> 
              <select data-toggle="tooltip"
                title="ÁREA DE TEXTO OBRIGATÓRIO" required="required"
                ng-model="pessoa.pessoasEnderecos.pais.idPais"
                ng-options="pai.idPais as pai.nome for pai in paises " 
              class="js-single"
                style="width: 100%; margin-top: -10px;" id="paisPais">
                <option ></option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

se alguem poder me ajudar

Comment: Olá. já tentou forçar o change após a mudança do valor? `$('#paisPais').trigger('change');`? talvez devido ao angular o update não está disparando o trigger de change e o valor não aparece na tela.

Comment: Sim ja tentei, mais no entrar no modal nada aparece, somente se eu selecionar o select dai a opção correta aparece dentro de um span. mais no caso ele tem que aparecer na hora que eu clicar em editar abrir o modal e esta la a opção salva pelo o usuario, entende.

Comment: Pesquisando um pouco vi essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819709/clear-select2-without-triggering-change-event#31856728) que diz para usarmos um outro evento `$('#paisPais').trigger('change.select2');` talvez funcione.

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui no site do select e realmente funciona quando utilizamos o `$('#paisPais').trigger('change.select2');', primeiro mudei o valor direto utilizando `val("valor")` e nada mudou no select, depois do `trigger('change.select2');` o valor foi atualizado no span.

Answer (score 0):

Após alterar o valor no angular, dispare o evento `change.select2` do próprio select2

```
$('#paisPais').trigger('change.select2');
```

assim o valor será atualizado em toda a estrutura do elemento, inclusive nos spans que vc comentou.